# How to bypass iget-object method return with value

Tags: smali

method public getPremium()Ljava/lang/String;
    .registers 2

```
.line 1
iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/myapp/android/api/models/User;->premium:Ljava/lang/String;

return-object v0
```

.end method

Comment: please provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

The line `iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/myapp/android/api/models/User;->premium:Ljava/lang/String;` is getting a `String` into v0.

You can alter the String (and `getPremium()` return value) this way:

```
method public getPremium()Ljava/lang/String; 
.registers 2

.line 1
iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/myapp/android/api/models/User;->premium:Ljava/lang/String;

const-string v0, "new value here?"

return-object v0
.end method
```